# Add a field in doc if it does not exist else update

Tags: python, pymongo

I am using the below code to update `job_start_time` in a doc:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://10.64.127.94:27017/")
mydb = myclient["UPTeam"]
mycol = mydb["perf_sdwan_queue"]
myquery = {"$and":[ {"job_job_id": current_job_id}, {"job_queue_name": "CURIE_BLR"}]}
my_jobs = mycol.find(myquery)
newvalues = { "$set": { "job_start_time":datetime.datetime.utcnow()} }
mycol.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
```

This works fine if the field exists. I want to have a code where it either updates the field if it exists else to create a new field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to change anything. `$set` will create the field if it doesn't exist, or update it if it does.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
> specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
> constraint.